# I want to create api that takes phone number along with country code and save it into database

Tags: laravel, api

I am new to laravel and I am trying to create a API in laravel where I have to save phone number along with country code in the database but I have no idea how can I do that any
suggestions will be really appreciated. I have also pasted screenshot of the phone number input field design which is attached below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUaNp.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the phone number field is varchar
2. Then follow the Documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#inserts to save the input